# Unable to drop constraint - SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a constraint checking the positivity of column and am unable to drop the constraint, or to be exact I'm not even clear the constraint exists. Attempting to drop the constraint gives an error message:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Test
DROP CONSTRAINT chk_positive;
```

Msg 3728, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
'chk_positive' is not a constraint.
Msg 3727, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors

But then experimenting and trying to re-add the constraint suggests its already exists

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Test
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_positive CHECK (n_example > 0);
```

Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "chk_positive ". The conflict occurred in database "...", table "dbo.Test", column 'n_example'.

Looking at the results of `SELECT * FROM sys.check_constraints` there is no mention of the `chk_positive` constraint, however other constraints I created are there.

Any idea why this might be occurring? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, the name-space for constraint names is the entire schema, not just the table.

In other words, two tables cannot have the same constraint name.  In general, when I name constraints, I include the table name (in your case, `chk_test_positive` would be a more likely name).

You can use `information_schema.table_constraints` to see the list of constraints.  There should be a `chk_positive` that is defined on another table.

My advice:  Include the table name in the constraint name.

Answer (score 0):

Try show every constrain. My guess is a capitalize issue, try using `[]`

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS ConstraintName,
       SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS SchemaName,
       OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) AS TableName,
       type_desc AS ConstraintType
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type_desc LIKE ‘%CONSTRAINT’
```

Answer (score 0):

Please run the following query under the database you are working. You will get the check constraint you have created already(if present) and the corresponding table name. As others guessed the check constraint you have created might have been created mistakenly on some other table. Then you can proceed accordingly.

```
 select 
        cc.name
        ,cc.object_id
        ,SysObj.name "TableName"
        ,cc.parent_object_id 
FROM sys.check_constraints cc
INNER JOIN sys.objects SysObj 
            on cc.parent_object_id=SysObj.object_id
WHERE LOWER(cc.name) LIKE '%positive%'
```